# Killing All Seagulls With Minimal Effort and Repercusions

Tags: internal-consistency, utopia

You read the title. I want them gone.

Comment: A huge quantity of poisoned french fries scattered on the beach should do it.

Comment: NOOOOOOOO! I love seagulls...

Comment: This is not about worldbuilding. It is about bird-acide. Therefore, it is not on topic for this site. On a side note, PedroGabriel (a frequent user) is already using 'Der Wanderer' in his profile pic. Great Romantic painting, though.

Comment: @kingledion Yeah, it's by far one of the most beautiful paintings I've seen.   And it actually fits with the story I'm creating. It's based around the echoes of a species dropping from the food chain. I just need a plausible reason for it to drop out.

Comment: Just a little hint: the body of your post is really short. Normally you should try to explain things like the technological level, the time, things you considered, etc. if you want a question to fit this sites guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

Strain of avian bird flu jumps species to humans. Seagulls are carriers only, but it is lethal to us. It spreads rapidly through the seagull populations of the coasts. Only thing to do is what we do with any bird population that exposes us to that virus: we kill it with a vengeance. Several million ducks/poultry killed in China during the last outbreak. Once the call goes out to "take 'em out!", it won't take long to go extinct. The passenger pigeon vanished in just a 19 years (hunted for fashionable feathers), from billions of birds (literally) to none. Our species is much more efficient these days with hunting. Just license permits and I bet every seagull in existence could be purged in a couple years.

http://www.audubon.org/magazine/may-june-2014/why-passenger-pigeon-went-extinct

Comment: It's sad that it really doesn't get much better than this.